# Get a function from an array, javascript

Tags: javascript

Got an array with functions. I want to do a function that returns a function from the array with function name given as argument.

```
var arr = [
  function Dog(){},
  function Cat(){}
];



var getFunction = function(name){
    return // should return the function with matching name
};

var dogFunction = getFunction('Dog'); // returns dog function.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcjd9pyz/

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you do an associative array, it is possible

```
var arr = {
    'dog' : function Dog(){},
    'cat' : function Cat(){}
};

arr['dog']();
```

Comment: And to get the function:  `var myFcuntion = arr['functionName'];`

Comment: @Logar314159 I don't get your comment

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I think Logar314159 meant something like:     arr.getFunction = function(name) {
      return this[name];
    } ... this would give the syntax requested in the question. Not sure it's necessary, but if so...

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe. I Already edited the comment, it was unclear, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Functions have a `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name):

```
var getFunction = function(name){
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i].name===name) return arr[i];
    }
    return // return undefined
};
```

If you want to have a fast access, you can precompute a map by first iterating:

```
var map = arr.reduce(function(m,f){ m[f.name]=f; return m}, {});
```

which allows

```
var fun = map["Dog"];
```

Computing the map in code instead of typing it yourself lets you not repeat the name. A DRY code is easier to maintain.

EDIT: I'm not sure functions have a name on IE but I can't test it.

Comment: Very huge amounts I'm working with. Is this or doing it as an associative array fastest?

Comment: @PerStröm An associative array is faster but you should check it really matters

Comment: According to Mozilla.org, the `name` function property is not supported in Internet Explorer. You could polyfill it by extracting the function's name from the value returned by `toString()`

Comment: What is an associative array? I thought that was something they had in PHP.

Comment: @torazaburo That's another name for what you probably know as a map. Any object is (about) an "associative array" in JS, meaning you can set and get properties by name

Comment: @DenysSéguret Sorry, forgot the smilie, was meant to be a sarcastic comment about the incorrect use of the term "associative array" in a JS context.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you could do it without modifying the array (or in all browsers except Internet Explorer if you replace the arrow function with a normal one and use a polyfill for [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill):

```
var getFunction = function(name){
    return arr.find( func => name === func.name );
};
```

Even in ES6 though, I don't see a good reason to do that. I think you should follow [Deblaton Jean-Philippe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34597294/772035) and change the array to an object, mapping the names to the functions.

Comment: This won't work. Either remove the curly brackets, or add a `return`. Also, you're mixing up `el` and `func`. MIssed morning coffee?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample work around of mine, instead of matching for string you can use it based on function name

https://gist.github.com/freewayz/56bd9db6d4164a42be75

```
var myArray = [{"name" : "pitaside", "id" : 1}, {"name":"github", "id" : 3}]
filterArrayByType: function (arrayToMatch, fieldType, matcher) {
        if(! arrayToMatch instanceof Array){throw ("Not an Array")}
        var filterTypeToReturn = arrayToMatch.filter((items) => {
                var temp;
                if (items[String(fieldType)] === matcher) {
                    temp = items[String(fieldType)]
                }
                return temp;
            }
        );
        return filterTypeToReturn;
}
var myMatcher = 'github'
var id3 = filterArrayByType(myArray, 'name', myMatcher)[0].id

//returns 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Function.prototype.toString()`. Unlike `name` it is supported by most of the modern browsers as well as by Node.js.

```
var arr = [
    function  Dog ( ) {},
    function  Cat ( ) {}
];

var getFunction = function(name){
    'use strict';
    // could use find but it isn't supported by IE
    return arr.filter(function (func) {
        return /^function\s+(\w+)/.exec(func.toString())[1] === name;
    })[0];
};

console.log(getFunction('Dog'));
console.log(getFunction('Cat'));
console.log(getFunction('Unknown'));
```

Comment: Won't work, because `\w` does not include dollar sign etc.

Comment: what browsers don't support it?